# Does 10.10.192.0/20 represent the same number of address with 10.10.195.0/20

Tags: ip, subnet

I knew `10.10.192.0/20` can represent the ip addresses from `10.10.192.0 to 10.10.207.255`, but I'm confused how does `10.10.195.0/20` represent? I guess it is same with 192.0/20 right?

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains it.

Comment: Thank you Ron, could you please give me a short answer: yes or no, then I will digest the long explanation link you gave me.

Comment: Yes it will because 195 is in the range. It's considered as an ip address between 192 and 207. Check the link of Ron and then take a look at this link https://www.calculator.net/ip-subnet-calculator.html. That subnet has 4096 hosts